# MySQL FOREIGN key not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I posted a question here and as per the response I am trying to create the following MySQL table, but it does not work, however, if I remove the two foreign commands it works

```
$query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS picture(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB";
mysql_query($query,$con);

$query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB";
mysql_query($query,$con);

$query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pictureRating
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pictureID INT NOT NULL,
userID INT NOT NULL,
rater INT NOT NULL,
creationDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
context VARCHAR(150),
rating TINYINT,

PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (pictureID) REFERENCES picture(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES user(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB";
mysql_query($query,$con)
```

I can't figure out why the tables fail to get created

Comment: Can you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE picture` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE user` after running your script? Also please post the output of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Also you said that you successfully created the table without the foreign key constraints. What commands do you run between each time you test your script to restore the database to its initial condition? Please post the exact commands.

Comment: @Mark: the Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE picture` is very large, it won't fit inside this comment. What is the convention here, should I click the "Answer your own question" button? The output basically indicates the structure I created

Comment: @Mark here is the error message I get from `mysql_error()` `Can't create table 'DB13.pictureRating' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to drop **all three tables** before you run your script.

It's not enough just to drop the `pictureRating` table. You could have old versions of the first two tables which could cause the creation of the third table to fail with the foreign key constraints, but succeed when you omit them.

When I delete all three tables and then try running your commands it works fine.

Comment: The thing is I'm creating a new Database every time (from PHP) so It can't be an issue with not dropping previous tables.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. The user table was in another database. I dropped all the tables, as you suggested, brought the user table into this database and restarted everything. Thanks